# Translating raw SQL IF with subqueries to DQL

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I have written a sql query that fits my needs, but im not really sure how to translate it to dql.

the raw sal query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
*,
FROM
photos, articles WHERE photos.id=if(
    (
        SELECT order_id FROM articles WHERE id=(
            SELECT article_id FROM gallery_articles WHERE id=
                (
                    SELECT galleryArticle_id FROM photos WHERE id=10
                )
        )
    ),0,10
) AND articles.order_id=2
```

How could I translate the if with the sub-queries?

Comment: What's your question? Note that code conversion requests are offtopic.

Comment: Not everything what can be done with plain SQL is doable in DQL, because DQL is - simply said - SQL for entities. You should describe how your entities look like and what is the desired outcome.